# how to return anonymous field from Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get anonymous field from Linq query.My query is

```
from p in product
Select new myProduct
{
  id = p.Id,
  Name = p.Name,
  P.MobileNo
}

//Here is myProduct class 

class myProduct
{
   public int Id,
   public string Name
}
```

Now here **P.MobileNo** is anonymous and I also want to return that.I cannot change anything in myProduct class.

anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. MobileNo is not "anonymous", it doesn't exist. There is no way to assign a field that doesn't exist...

Comment: There is no `anonymous property`. You cannot even send back `anonymous class` from a **method** to another. But if you are using .NET 4.5, you can do so. How? use `dynamic class`.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use an anonymous type

```
from p in product
select new
{
  p.Id,
  p.Name,
  p.MobileNo
}
```

Or create another named type that contains `MobileNo` property. If you need to return this from a method

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that will inherit from myProduct.

```
class myProduct
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
class mySecondProduct : myProduct
{
   public string MobileNo {get;set;}
}
```

In Linq:

```
from p in product
Select new mySecondProduct
{
  id = p.Id,
  Name = p.Name,
  P.MobileNo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the myProduct object and P.MobileNo in an anonymous type:

```
from p in product
select new
{
    Product = new myProduct { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name},
    MobileNo = P.MobileNo
}
```